# PFFacebookUtils. How to make difference between login and signup?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, parse-platform, pffacebookutils

I'm trying to provide some very simple (as I thought) functionality into my application which uses `Parse.com` service. What I need is just allow users to create an account via Facebook and login them again via Facebook.

The problem is that `PFFacebookUtils` login methods not only login users through Facebook but also create a new `PFUser`. Why is it a problem for me? Well, of course. I can distinguish between signing up and in by `isNew` field but it doesn't really help.

Consider the following - user tries to login via Facebook (he doesn't any have `PFUser` yet), he loggs in, a new user is created. I see that the user is new (i.e. the user wasn't registered before) and I have to reject this login. Ok, I reject him, I say "You haven't been registered yet, go and sign up". User signs up (via the same login method) and this time the same `PFUser` is returned which was created when the user tried to log in. I see that the user is not new, it has already been registered and therefore I have to reject the user again, because the account already exists and it is impossible to create the same account again.

Do you understand the problem? Am I being idiotic not realizing how to deal with `PFFacebookUtils` account creation and logging in or it is `PFFacebookUtils` who provides an idiotic API? How do you people do that? How do you solve the problem that I've described. Really, it must be so simple but I can't find a good example anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have login and signup code in swift that checks to see if a user is new in login and signup. Here is my code:

***LOGIN***

```
let spinningActivity = MBProgressHUD.showHUDAddedTo(self.view, animated: true)
    spinningActivity.label.text = "Just a Moment"
    spinningActivity.detailsLabel.text = "Logging in"

    if reachabilityStatus == kNOTREACHABLE {

        spinningActivity.hideAnimated(true)

        self.displayError("No Internet Connection", message: "Please connect to the internet before continuing")

    } else {

        let permissions = ["public_profile"]

        PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissions) { (user:PFUser?, error:NSError?) -> Void in



            if error != nil {

                spinningActivity.hideAnimated(true)

                self.displayError("Error", message: error!.localizedDescription)

            } else if let user = user {
                if user.isNew {

                    spinningActivity.hideAnimated(true)

                    PFUser.currentUser()?.deleteInBackground()

                    self.displayNoticeWithTwoActions("Account Not Found", message: "This Facebook account is not in our system. You have to sign up first.", firstButtonTitle: "Sign Up",closeButtonTitle: "Ok", segue: "dontHaveAccountSegue")

                } else {

                    spinningActivity.hideAnimated(true)

                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("successfulLoginSegue", sender: self)



                }
            } else {

                PFUser.currentUser()?.deleteInBackground()

                spinningActivity.hideAnimated(true)

                self.displayError("Error", message: "Unless you tapped on 'Cancel' or 'Done', something went wrong. Please try again.")

            }

        }

    }
```

***SIGNUP***

I have a signup button and then a function that is implemented into the login button called "loadFacebookUserDetails"

```
let spinningActivity = MBProgressHUD.showHUDAddedTo(self.view, animated: true)
    spinningActivity.label.text = "Just a Moment"
    spinningActivity.detailsLabel.text = "Loading Details"


    if reachabilityStatus == kNOTREACHABLE {

        spinningActivity.hideAnimated(true)

       self.displayError("No Internet Connection", message: "Please connect to the internet before continuing")

    } else {

        let permissions = ["public_profile", "email"]

        PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissions) { (user:PFUser?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

            if let user = user {

                if !user.isNew {

                    spinningActivity.hideAnimated(true)

                    PFUser.logOut()


                    self.displayNoticeWithTwoActions("Account Found", message: "This Facebook account already in our system. You have to log in first.", firstButtonTitle: "Log In", closeButtonTitle: "Cancel", segue: "haveAccountSegue")



                } else if error != nil {

                    spinningActivity.hideAnimated(true)

                    self.displayError("Error", message: error!.localizedDescription)



                } else if error == nil {

                    spinningActivity.hideAnimated(true)

                    self.loadFacebookUserDetails()

                }

            }

       else {

                spinningActivity.hideAnimated(true)

                self.displayError("Something Went Wrong", message: "Unless you tapped on 'Cancel' or 'Done', something went wrong. Please try again")

            }



        }


    }
```

---

```
func loadFacebookUserDetails() {

    let spinningActivity = MBProgressHUD.showHUDAddedTo(self.view, animated: true)
    spinningActivity.mode = MBProgressHUDMode.AnnularDeterminate
    spinningActivity.label.text = "Just a Moment"
    spinningActivity.detailsLabel.text = "Loading Details"

    let requestPerameters = ["fields": "id, email, first_name, last_name, name"]

    let userDetails = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: requestPerameters)

    userDetails.startWithCompletionHandler { (connection, result, error:NSError!) -> Void in

        if error != nil {

            spinningActivity.hideAnimated(true)

            self.displayError("Error", message: error!.localizedDescription)

            PFUser.logOut()

        } else {

        let userID:String = result["id"] as! String
        let userEmail:String = result["email"] as! String
        let userFirstName:String = result["first_name"] as! String
        let userLastName:String = result["last_name"] as! String


        // Get Facebook Profile Picture

        let userProfile = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + userID + "/picture?type=large"

        let usernameLink = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + userID

        let username = usernameLink.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("https://graph.facebook.com/", withString: "")

        let profilePictureUrl = NSURL(string: userProfile)

        let profilePictureData = NSData(contentsOfURL: profilePictureUrl!)

        if profilePictureData != nil {

            let profilePictureObject = PFFile(data: profilePictureData!)
            PFUser.currentUser()?.setObject(profilePictureObject!, forKey: "profile_picture")

        }

        PFUser.currentUser()?.setObject(userFirstName, forKey: "first_name")
        PFUser.currentUser()?.setObject(userLastName, forKey: "last_name")
        PFUser.currentUser()?.setObject(username, forKey: "facebook_link")

        if userEmail == userEmail {

            PFUser.currentUser()?.email = userEmail

        }

        PFUser.currentUser()?.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success:Bool, error:NSError?) -> Void in

            if error != nil {

                spinningActivity.hideAnimated(true)

                self.displayError("Error", message: error!.localizedDescription)

                PFUser.logOut()

            } else if success == true {

                if !userID.isEmpty {

                    spinningActivity.hideAnimated(true)

                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject("authData", forKey: "facebookAuth")

                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("facebookUserDetailsSegue", sender: self)



                }

            } else {

                spinningActivity.hideAnimated(true)

                self.displayError("Something Went Wrong", message: "Please try again")

                PFUser.logOut()

            }

        })

    }

}

}
```

If you have trouble with the conversion to objective c, I bet you can find YouTube videos on how to do this.